# XML parsing attributes

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

My XML File Looks similar to this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Document>
     <Fruits>
        <Attr N="Orange" V="23.0" />
        <Attr N="Apple" V="10" />
        <Attr N="Pear" V="0.000000" />
     </Fruits>
     <Customer>
        <Attr N="Package" V="Box" />
        <Attr N="Cashier" V="P26" />
        <Attr N="Type" V="2" />
        <Attr N="Policy" V="25C" />
     </Customer>
     <OrderInfo>
        <Attr N="PartNumber" V="CP231" />
        <Attr N="Qty" V="2" />
        <Attr N="Salesman" V="Joe" />
     </OrderInfo>
     <OrderInfo>
        <Attr N="PartNumber" V="CD131" />
        <Attr N="Qty" V="3" />
        <Attr N="Salesman" V="Joe" />
     </OrderInfo>
  </Document>
```

I am trying to extract the PartNumber and Qty both the N and V from the OrderInfo but for some reason my code never works, this was my code, would appreciate any help I can get.

```
 Dim xmlSource As New XmlTextReader("Test.xml")
    Dim xml = XDocument.Load(xmlSource)
    Dim trs = xml.Root.Descendants("OrderInfo").ToList()
    For Each CalculatedPrice In trs
        Dim tds = CalculatedPrice.Descendants("Attr")
        For Each Attr As XElement In tds
            Dim atr As XAttribute = Attr.Attribute("N")
            If Not (atr.Value = Nothing) Then
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", atr.Value))

            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "my code never works"? I've just run your exact code, and it printed out "PartNumber
Qty
Salesman
PartNumber
Qty
Salesman"

Comment: You should add what output you are getting or any error message you have encountered. That would help other contributors find the issue quickly.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Just a thought, but that XML looks a little uncommon, with Elements named "Attribute" and attributes named "Name" and "Value" (N & V). Attributes themselves are name='value'.

Comment: I'd recommend using XmlDocument, and the SelectNodes, and finally call GetAttribute() on the results.

Comment: @William Walseth : That is a terrible recommendation.  Xml linq is much better at parsing this xml.

Comment: @jdweng My example below is pretty tight, light and repeatable.  Don't fear the XPath (ha ha) Have a good w/e.

Comment: Why do you only recommend XmlDocument and not XDocument?  And you are only getting OrderInfo and Customer nor Fruits.  And you hard coded the V and N.  What if you have all the attributes A to Z?

Comment: We'll likely never agree and that's fine, I guess Linq is powerful, but IMHO, the code looks like a overly complex regular expression, and there are so many methods to know and understand.  I recommend XmlDocument because it's so simple and powerful, you really only need to know XPath, and 3 DOM methods, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode and GetAttribute.  It creates easy to read code, that is easy for a large team to work on together.  Both of your suggested changes can be completed with the example, just change the XPath.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, so the issue I run into is when I try to print this out to a form app I cannot do it as easily as writing just to a console does anyone know what équivalent this would be on forms?

Answer (score 0):

See code below :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim xml = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim trs As List(Of XElement) = xml.Root.Descendants("OrderInfo").ToList()
        For Each CalculatedPrice As XElement In trs
            Dim tds As List(Of XElement) = CalculatedPrice.Descendants("Attr").ToList()
            For Each Attr As XElement In tds
                Dim atr As XAttribute = Attr.Attribute("N")
                If Not (atr.Value = Nothing) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", atr.Name.LocalName, CType(atr, String))

                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example.

```
    Imports System.Xml

    Module Module1
            Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"

            Sub Main()
                    Dim xml As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
                    xml.Load(FILENAME)
' Original, Attributes of OrderInfo

                    For Each ndRow As XmlElement In xml.SelectNodes("//OrderInfo/Attr")
                            Console.WriteLine(ndRow.GetAttribute("N") + ":" + ndRow.GetAttribute("V"))
                    Next

' All attributes for Fruit and OrderInfo
                For Each ndRow As XmlAttribute In xml.SelectNodes("//Attr/@*")
                        Console.WriteLine(ndRow.Value)
                Next

                ' All attributes for just Fruit
                For Each ndRow As XmlAttribute In xml.SelectNodes("//*[not(OrderInfo)]/Attr/@*")
                        Console.WriteLine(ndRow.Value)
                Next

            End Sub

    End Modul
```